# Ruby on Rails 3.4 nested forms - fields_for creates multiple entries in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested

I'm having a problem with the way Rails stores my nested form in the DB. I am designing a recipes website (hobby) for which I created three models Recipe, Ingredient and IngredientRecipe (code below). Ingredients are accessed via has_many through by Recipe. So recipes can have many ingredients and ingredients can belong to many recipes. Furthermore, the IngredientRecipe model hold the quantity, unique to every combination of recipe and ingredient.

My problem is not creating the nested form for entering the data but the way it is being stored in the DB. With my current code every new entry generates two rows in the IngredienRecipe model, one for the combination of Recipe and quantity and one for the Recipe ingredient relation. However, I am trying to set it up in a way where each entry generates exactly one row in the ingredient_recipes table, linking together a unique combination of recipe, ingredient and quantity.

Any tips or code snippets are highly appreciated, as I have been stuck with this problem for a few days now :-(

Here are my current models:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :description, :name
      attr_accessible :ingredients_attributes, :ingredient_recipes_attributes

      has_many :ingredient_recipes
      has_many :ingredients, :through => :ingredient_recipes

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient_recipes
  end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :unit

      has_many :ingredient_recipes
      has_many :recipes, :through => :ingredient_recipes
     end

class IngredientRecipe < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :quantity

      belongs_to :recipe
      belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

The modified recipes controller:

```
   #Modified controller function
    def new
        @recipe = Recipe.new
        @ingredients = @recipe.ingredients.build
        @ingredient_recipes = @recipe.ingredient_recipes.build

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @recipe }
        end
      end
```

And the form_for view file

```
<%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

<%=f.fields_for :ingredients do |ff|%>
   <div class="field">
    <%= ff.label :name %><br />
    <%= ff.text_field :name %>
  </div>

     <%= f.fields_for :ingredient_recipes do |fff| %>
         <div class="field">
           <%= fff.label :quantity%><br />
           <%= fff.text_field :quantity %>
         </div>
  <% end -%>   

  <div class="field">
    <%= ff.label :unit %><br />
    <%= ff.text_field :unit %>
  </div>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
   <% end %>
```

OK, after going over my code many many times, I finally came up with a better solution to my problem. The trick lies in nesting the models in each other through Recipe --> Ingredient --> JOIN table. My current solution does not dynamically add fields_for yet, however this version does not require any changes to the recipes_controller. In case someone else is struggling with this as well, here is my code:

```
    class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :ingredients_attributes

  has_many :unique_recipes
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :unique_recipes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients

end

class UniqueRecipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :quantity, :recipe_id, :ingredient_id

    belongs_to :recipe
    belongs_to :ingredient

end


class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :unit, :unique_recipes_attributes

  has_many :unique_recipes
  has_many :recipes, :through => :unique_recipes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :unique_recipes, allow_destroy: true

end


<%= form_for @recipe, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name, :class => %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
    <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
      <%= f.text_area :description, :class => 'text_area' %>

<%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.label :name, :class => %>
      <%= ff.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
    <%= ff.label :unit, :class => %>
      <%= ff.text_field :unit, :class => 'text_field' %>
  <%= ff.fields_for :unique_recipes do |fff| %>
    <%= fff.label :quantity, :class => %>
      <%= fff.text_field :quantity, :class => 'text_field' %>
<% end -%>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                recipes_path, :class => 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: building  @ ingredients = @ recipe.ingredients.build should save the value in join table you dont need this  @ ingredients = @recipe.ingredients.build in your controller . since you are buliding your join model twice its saving it two times.

Comment: Hello @Ragh, thank you for your feedback. The purpose of the [at] ingredients = [at] recipe.ingredients.build in the recipes_controller is to make the respective entry fields visible when creating a new recipe. Taking either the [at]ingredients or the [at]ingredient_recipes out of the controller removes the according form fields in the view. What I want to achieve is to be able to create a recipe with all its ingredients and quantities from within the Recipe model.

Comment: I can replace  <%=f.fields_for :ingredients do |ff|%> with <%=f.fields_for @ ingredients = @ recipe.ingredients.build do |ff|%> in the form field and this still gives me all necessary form elements. However, I can no longer store the form as I get an "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: ingredient" with the following parameters : "{
 "recipe"=>{"name"=>"13",
 "description"=>"123",
 "ingredient"=>{"name"=>"123",
 "unit"=>"123"},
 "ingredient_recipes_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"quantity"=>"123"}}},
 "commit"=>"Create Recipe"}"

Comment: @Raghu , thank you for your tip again. I believe that you are right about the double build. I can narrow down my issues to the @ ingredients = @ recipe.ingredients.build in the new function of my recipes_controller. However, if I try to move this statement to the fields_form of the _form view, I immediately run into a "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: ingredient". Do you maybe have a suggestion on where else I could look further? Thank you for your help so far and cheers.

Comment: If this is solved, can you write up the solution as an answer to the question? It'd help others with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

And here is my current and working solution for the nested form fields with a has_many through association and the cocoon gem to dynamically add fields. I am still working on some cocoon tweaking for this particular scenario, but the model and the associations do work.

The models:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :ingredients_attributes

  has_many :unique_recipes
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :unique_recipes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients

end

class UniqueRecipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :quantity, :recipe_id, :ingredient_id

    belongs_to :recipe
    belongs_to :ingredient

end


class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :unit, :unique_recipes_attributes

  has_many :unique_recipes
  has_many :recipes, :through => :unique_recipes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :unique_recipes, allow_destroy: true

end
```

The form field with some mixed in Twitter bootstrap:

```
    <%= form_for @recipe, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_area :description, :class => 'text_area' %>
    </div>
  </div>

<%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |ff| %>
<%= render 'ingredient_fields', f: ff %>

<% end -%>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add an Ingredient', f, :ingredients, :class => 'btn btn-  primary'%>
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                recipes_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And the matching partial _ingredient_fields.html.erb

```
   <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :name, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :unit, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :unit, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%=link_to_remove_association "Remove Ingredient", f%>

  <%= render 'quantity_fields', f: ff %>
<% end -%>
```

There are no changes to the recipes_controller. If you would like to have the ability to dynamically add and remove nested form elements, I can highly recommend the cocoon gem (http://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).

Cheers!